# Chat Server Architecture for a Customer Service Software

Tags: node.js, xmpp, rabbitmq, openfire, livechat

I need to provide Chat Contact in a site where the visitors can chat with operators. The chats are channeled into different business organized queues: sales, support, product information, etc.
Can you suggest me an architecture that would cover:

- Server side chat server with the queue routing, DB, operators online status, etc.
- Operator web application
- Visitors Operators
- Real time monitoring web site

I am taking a look to:

- node.js + Socket.io + Redis pub/sub: I have to implement all the messaging system
- XMPP server like Openfire
- RabbitMQ

What youd you suggest? any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: You are right on but would add MongoDB to store customer contacts chat history as its a real pain to have to reiterate your last chat to another representative.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to take a look at the [Fastpath service](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp) and webchat for Openfire.  It provides at least some of this functionality.

Comment: I did and it looks like it cover some of the requirements. The product seems robust but I am not pretty sure about development agility and scalability given that is java and have lots of proprietary frameworks. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Monardo - Your comment about java and not scalable doesn't make any sense.  Architecture, not language typically determines scalability.  As for the proprietary nature, you were asking for ideas and suggestions.  I don't think there are any open standards regarding this topic, pretty much any solution will be proprietary.

Comment: Hi Robin, I don't know what happened with the downvote. I couldn't doit because I need at least '15 reputation'.

Comment: Hi Robin, I don't know what happened with the downvote. I couldn't doit because I need at least '15 reputation'. Regarding scalability, I wanted to mean architecture. Java webapp running under Jetty using continuations perform much better than other servlet container without them. NOde.js is known to be really good handling concurrency. Anyway, I took the first step towards to Openfire. It's been for a long time in the market and there are LOTS of feature already done. I am trying to put together a product and not just a chat room example and then build everything else. Thanks Robin.